# Scheduling a single thread across different processors - need to clear cache?

Tags: multithreading, caching, scheduling, processor

When you schedule a single thread across different processors, does the cache have to be cleared each time? If the cache is not cleared, can't the following happen :

Suppose you have the following (pseudo) code executed by 2 processors, P1 and P2.

```
     1. foo() {
     2. int x=5;
     3. x=10;
     4. print x;
     5. }
```

Initially the thread is scheduled on P1, which executes lines 1 and 2, and stores 5 in its cache for x's memory location (on the stack).

The thread is then scheduled on P2 which executes line 3, and stores 10 in *its* cache for x's memory location.

Finally, the thread is again scheduled on P1, and executing line 4, prints 5 (x's value in P1's cache).

Yet we clearly expect 10 to be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the processor caches/registers would need to be updated, or at least flushed to main memory, so the thread could get at its recent memory if it migrated to another core/processor.

Luckily the common server/desktop platforms we usually write code for are [cache coherent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence), so the hardware takes care of all the magic to make this work right, and an operating system would anyway need to ensure that the proper memory given to a thread/process are available wherever the operating system decides to run that thread. This is not a task that application code should need to worry about.

In the case you're on a platform that's not cache-coherent, you would probably know - and most likely the OS/thread library you use would take care of making sure the caches are properly updated if the OS decides to migrate a thread to another processor.